# (When) does SharePoint Online in Microsoft 365 use the Microsoft Upload Center?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office

When opening Office Documents from Microsoft 365 it seems that the Microsoft Upload Center is not being used: I can open Word-documents from a document library and save them back without a problem, even when I clicked 'Pause Uploads'. Also: files do not show up under 'Recently upload files'.

I'm using Office 2016.

Answer (score 1):

On general, the Microsoft Upload Center is used when you access online content from OneDrive, OneDrive for Business, SharePoint Online or SharePoint Server.

It's often in use if you have a poor internet connection and saves your document to the Document Cache and keeps it there until you have a solid internet connection.

To make use of offline content in Office 365, you use OneDrive for Business sync client, which synchronizes your selected folders locally, making access faster and synchronization faster.

Reference:

- [What Is the Microsoft Office Upload Center, and Should You Disable It?](http://www.howtogeek.com/253587/what-is-the-microsoft-office-upload-center-and-should-you-disable-it/)
- [Get started with the new OneDrive sync client in Windows](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-started-with-the-new-OneDrive-sync-client-in-Windows-615391c4-2bd3-4aae-a42a-858262e42a49?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: I understand what you are saying and I was already aware of the general functionality. Maybe my question wasn't clear enough: to be more specific, I'm looking for the factors that decide whether or not the upload center is used when accessing online content in a specific case. For instance: is it dependent on bandwith? And if so, at which moment (kpbs) does it kick in?

Comment: @RobertWagenaar  Oh, that's a tough one. My guess is that it doesn't really care about general bandwidth specs, but the current state of the connection. Even if I have 100/100 GBit/s speed here I don't always have that at the other end (aka MS). So if they're busy, the Upload Center kicks in.